# How to enforce uniqueness on a table that has data in child table

Tags: mysql, sql

In a green field project, I have an entity `Resource` which has many child entities `Attributes`. To model the schema, I'm creating a FK in the attributes table.

Resource has `name` and `id`, Attributes has `resourceId` and attribute `name` and attribute `value`.

The `number of attributes` and the `name and value of those attributes` has to be unique for a resource name. I have not been able to enforce uniqueness for resource at the database level.

For example, 
mmg(id:1) has (a:1,b:abc) `valid`
mmg(id:2) has (a:1) `valid`
mmg(id:3) has (a:1,b:abc) `not valid`

On the resource table, mmg(id:2) is totally valid since it has only one attribute compare to the rest but mmg (id:3) is not since it has the same exact attributes as mmg (id:1). It is basically the same resource.

mmg(id:3) should not exist because they have same `name` and `attributes` and `same number of attributes`. I can enforce uniqueness programmatically, however was wondering if there is way to enforce it at database level and possibly redesign the tables or query for easier and efficient lookups.

[image: Resource Table]
[image: Attributes Table]

I need to query this table and find the exact resource using its attributes. For that I wrote the following query and works fine (may not be optimized though since a resource can have many attributes and the query will become very long) :

```
select * from (SELECT 
    groupedByResourceId.resource_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        taggedElements.resource_id,
            COUNT(*) AS count1,
            SUM(taggedElements.a_ind) AS a_sum,
            SUM(taggedElements.b_ind) AS b_sum
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        resource_id,
            CASE
                WHEN (name = 'a' AND value = '1') THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS a_ind,
            CASE
                WHEN (name = 'b' AND value = 'abc') THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS b_ind
    FROM
        resource_attribute) AS taggedElements
    GROUP BY 1) AS groupedByResourceId
WHERE
    groupedByResourceId.count1 = 2
        AND groupedByResourceId.a_sum = 1
        AND groupedByResourceId.b_sum = 1) as attr, resource where resource.id = attr.resource_id
```

note: On average each resource may have upto 20 attributes (including 0).

note: The resourceId is being used by couple other tables.

Comment: If there are already 20 attributes for a given resource, and someone attempts to insert another attribute, what do you want to happen?

Comment: I am not much concern about the maximum number of attributes they can add to a resource. It will potentially make the query longer and less perfomant, but the issue is currently they can insert same resource and its attributes multiple times. On the resource table, mmg(id:2) is totally valid since it has only one attribute, compare to the rest but mmg (id:3) is not since it has the same exact attributes as mmg(id:1).

Comment: Why do you have a table of name/value pairs for this? Ideally, you would just use actual columns for each possible attribute.

Comment: @jpmc26 The number of attributes and the name and value of them is dynamic and different.  A resource is defined by its attributes and a resource_name.

Comment: Why do you need to query by all of its attributes? If you know them all, what is the query getting them for? And do you have any flexibility to change the schema?

Comment: Yes, I do have flexibility to change the schema, Example of usage: 
A resource name is `book` has attribute `isbn:123` and `cover:hard` and another resource is name is `book` with `isbn:999` and `cover:hard`. These are two different resources. The query will find the resourceId based on the provided attributes

Comment: @Alidad Okay, but what data is the query *getting* that it doesn't already know? Are there more columns on the first table? Or is it doing a search that might match partial data in the attribute table?

Comment: Also, do you have code outside the database where you can do things?

Comment: This is a java code. The resource table is just a name and id nothing more, but it's id is being used everywhere.  When I am querying I know the resourceName, and its attributes, its just matter of finding the resourceId and using that resourceId to find other information on other tables.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is to add a unique constraint on the `Attributes` table, on the two columns `name` and `value`:

```
ALTER TABLE Attributes ADD UNIQUE `idx` (`name`, `value`);
```

This will ensure that a given `resource_id` must have a unique combination of `name` and `value`.

You might be able to write a trigger to check that the number of rows for a given attribute would not exceed 20 after an insert.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that constraint wont solve the existing problem. A resource (name) by its attributes together should be unique. In my example, mmg(id:3) and its attributes should not be allowed to be inserted since mmg (id:1) already exist with the same attributes and same name.